# Create an object using Python's C API

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-extensions, python-embedding

Say I have my object layout defined as:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    // Other stuff...
} pyfoo;
```

...and my type definition:

```
static PyTypeObject pyfoo_T = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    // ...

    pyfoo_new,
};
```

How do I create a new instance of `pyfoo` somewhere within my C extension?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

<strike>Call [PyObject_New()](http://docs.python.org/c-api/allocation.html#PyObject_New), followed by [PyObject_Init()](http://docs.python.org/c-api/allocation.html#PyObject_Init).</strike>

**EDIT:** The best way is to [call](https://docs.python.org/c-api/call.html?highlight=pyobject_call#c.PyObject_Call) the class object, just like in Python itself:

```
/* Pass two arguments, a string and an int. */
PyObject *argList = Py_BuildValue("si", "hello", 42);

/* Call the class object. */
PyObject *obj = PyObject_CallObject((PyObject *) &pyfoo_T, argList);

/* Release the argument list. */
Py_DECREF(argList);
```

Comment: I agree the docs are a little terse in that case. I updated my answer with the required call to `PyObject_Init()`.

Comment: Wait, `PyObject_Init()` doesn't take any arguments, so how do you pass in the requisite initialisation arguments?

Comment: @detly, you need to call the class object. See my updated answer.

Comment: Aah, that makes more sense. Is it normal to get a compiler error ("assignment from incompatible pointer type")?

Comment: @detly, since `PyTypeObject` "derives" from `PyObject` internally, and an explicit cast is used, there should be no warning. What's your compiler?

Comment: GCC 4.4.5... and now that I've had a chance to check, it's only a warning, not an error.

Comment: If returning this instance to a Python function, I'm assuming I don't need to increment the retain count to be safe?

Comment: @jkp, if I'm not mistaken, the class object should already have `INCREF`ed the object it returned, because it just created it and intends to pass ownership to you in the first place. If you also intend to pass ownership of the new object to your caller, you should not `DECREF` it either. See http://edcjones.tripod.com/refcount.html for the gory details.

Comment: one-liner: PyObject_CallFunction((PyObject *)&pyfoo_T, "si", "hello", 42); combines PyObject_CallObject + Py_BuildValue

Comment: If there is only one argument, the Py_BuildValue call needs parenthesis in the format string.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "best"? Is there any reason to prefer CallObject over PyObject_New and PyObject_Init which are crossed out in the answer?

Comment: Is this answer out of date? I can't find it in documentation