# Create an instance of Python New Style class to embed in C++

Tags: python-2.7, class, instance, python-embedding, pyobject

I am working with `PyObject` to embed part of the `python` code inside `C++`. I found the solution that works well with `python 2.7` using `PyInstance_New` to create python instance. But it doesn't work with new style python classes which look like this.

```
    class B(object): 
      def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name

      def print_name(lastName): 
        print self.name + " " + lastName
```

In my older code(`python 2.7`), class definition doesn't inherit from object class and I create my instance to call `print_name` method like this. P.S. file name is A.py.

```
    PyObject *import, *attr, *instance, *methodcall, *arg, *tuple;
    arg = PyString_FromString("hello"); 
    tuple = PyTuple_Pack(1, arg);  

    import = PyImport_ImportModule("A"); 
    attr = PyObject_GetAttrString(import, "B");
    instance = PyInstance_New(attr, arg, NULL); 

    methodcall = PyObject_CallMethod(instance, (char *) "print_name", (char *) "(s)", (char *) "Bill");
```

But the code above doesn't work anymore because, in the new `python 3.x`, `type(class)` returns `object`, instead of `instance`. Now, I am getting this error.

> bad argument to internal function.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an object using Python's C API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163018/create-an-object-using-pythons-c-api)

Comment: As the linked question and [Barpaum](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40655558/369450) suggest, you should do: `instance = PyObject_CallObject(attr /*the class*/, tuple /*args in tuple*/);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this works for you. But I suggest you try it. Just use "PyObject_CallObject" to initialize an instance, then use "PyObject_CallMethod" to call a method of the instance.