# Python C API, tp_new function not getting called

Tags: python, api

I am developing a new Python data type using type objects. I used the "Defining New Types page for Python 2.7.12" as a guide and was able to adapt the examples on that page to my specific needs. I am able to create my new data type and add it to a Python module. When I run things from Python, I can create a new object like this.

```
x = MyNewType()
```

In this case, my `tp_new` function is called and I am able to fill in the default data items the way I want. However, if I try to do the same thing in C++ by calling `PyObject_New()`, my `tp_new` function doesn't get called. As a workaround I can call `PyObject_SetAttrString()` on each data member with no problem. I see the same issue with my `tp_init` function, where calling `PyObject_Init()` does not result in my `tp_init` function getting called. I've spent the better part of a day trying to track this thing down with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to [call](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Call) the class object, just like in Python itself.

Credit: I just learnt it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4163055/6059640) answer.