# Python C extension: How to return a new class instance?

Tags: python, c, class

Targeting Python 3.7+, how can one return a new class instance to Python code from a C extension?

Dictionaries, lists, tuples are easy (example of the latter):  `return Py_BuildValue("(OO)", Py_False, Py_None);`

This truly ancient thread (https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/99ack91fye/creating-python-class-instances-from-c-api) highlights `PyInstance_New()`. Which appears long since removed from the API.

Ideally there would be something like `Py_BuildClass("s{{s:s},{s,i}}","Dog","name","fido","age",11);`

Any thoughts welcomed.

P.S. Ideally *not* constructable from Python code. But that'd be icing on the cake.

P.P.S. To clarify. Assume the extension (call it Kennel) manages a Dog class:

```
struct Dog
{
    char* name;
    int age;
};
```

and my Python extension has a function which returns a Dog instance to a Python consumer. It would be good to be able to do this:

```
dog = kennel.getDog()
print(f"{dog.name} is {dog.age}")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163018/create-an-object-using-pythons-c-api . Short answer: you call the class, same as in Python

Comment: @user253751 OK, upon re-reading, not quite the question I was asking. I am not returning an instance of the extension type, but a new class. Think of it as a C function that returns a struct. Please see my P.P.S.

Comment: You want to return a whole new class every time? Not just a new instance of a class?

Comment: ideally yes. am open to any other suggestions.

Comment: why can't you just define the class once, and return a new instance each time? which you do like this: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html

Comment: looking for [`Py_BuildValue`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#building-values)?

Comment: @Thomas - thanks. am 100% down with `Py_BuildValue()`. Please see second paragraph of my question. What I'm asking is is there something similar to create a Python class instance? Not a tuple or dictionary. Thx.

Comment: sure, the other way is what user253751 suggested, defining a type and returning instances of that type. if you don't want to do it yourself, use some wrapper generating tooling like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) or [PyAutoC](https://github.com/orangeduck/PyAutoC)